# How to toggle ng class by clicking a checkbox button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Through webservice i used ngrepeat to show the check box.
It contains 10 check box. Check box was produced in div tag not used html input tag.

**In Html,**

```
<div ng-repeat="showproduct in showproducts.ProductList.products" class="col-md-3 mobile-two">
<div id="1" class="mSelected">{{showproduct.productName}}
</div>
```

**In controller,**

```
$http({
method  : 'POST',
url     : '///',
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
data:$.param({
userId:$localStorage.loginUserDet.LoginStatus.user.userId,
sessionId:$localStorage.loginUserDet.LoginStatus.sessionId,
authToken:$localStorage.loginUserDet.LoginStatus.user.authToken
})
})
.success(function(data)
{
alert("success");
$scope.showproducts= data;
console.log($scope.showproducts);
});
```

**JSon, to view the check box list**

```
{
"ProductList": {
"code": 0,
"products": [
  {
"productId": 1,
"productName": "Credit Card",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 2,
"productName": "Net Banking",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 3,
"productName": "Saving Account",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 4,
"productName": "Loan",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 5,
"productName": "Insurance",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 6,
"productName": "Certificate Of Deposit",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 7,
"productName": "Prepaid Card",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 8,
"productName": "Investment",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 9,
"productName": "All Products",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 10,
"productName": "Demo",
"productStatus": 1
},
  {
"productId": 11,
"productName": "Remittance",
"productStatus": 1
}
],
"uploadStatus": 1
}
}
```

I need to toggle the ngclass when i click the check obx. 
Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Where is the checkbox and where you want to toggle?

Comment: Checkbox is at <div id="1" class="mSelected"></div>. I guess is painted by mSelected css class.

Comment: Yes you are right @dbardelas

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to div behave like toggle, on click you the `selectTog()` will be called and adds `ClassName` because of `$scope.mSlected` varibale will become true in the same way it removes the class

```
<div id="1" ng-class="(mSelected ? 'ClassName': '')" ng-click="selectTog()">{{showproduct.productName}}</div>
```

now in controller

```
$scope.mSelected = false; // setting it false by default
$scope.selectTog = function(){
    $scope.mSelected = !$scope.mSelected;
}
```

**What if there is ng-repeat?**

remove `ng-class` from `<div>` and add class in the function.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4]"
    <div id="x" ng-click="selectTog($event)">{{x}}</div>
</div>
```

now in controller

```
$scope.selectTog = function(){
    $event.target.addClass("ClassName");
}
```

Comment: am not used input type.. its painted in the div

Comment: good answer, type a little explanation to make it even better for the readers and you get an upvote

Comment: Yes you are right but here i used ng repeat.. So if i click one check box means it selects all the check box

Comment: I have to check the selected checkbox only @Charan Cherry

Comment: can you please tell?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
<div id="1" ng-class="'mSelected': data" ng-click="toggle()">{{showproduct.productName}}</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.data = true;
$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.data = !$scope.data;
}
```

When ever you click the `div` it will toggle the class.

All the best.

Comment: Hey sai am not used the input type. I painted the checkbox in div

Comment: .mSelected {
    background-color: rgb(153, 198, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 6px 7px 6px 34px;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: Nice and impressive

Comment: Sai am not using input type. here u provided ngmodel with input type

Comment: I forgot to remove that. You can see this now.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class evaluates an expression like `ng-class="productSaleTrue ? onSale : notOnSale"`

```
<div ng-class="mSelected" ng-click="mSelected = !mSelected">
    {{showproduct.productName}}
</div>
```

This would evaluate to true and add the css class onSale to the element with that ng-class, if the expression would evaluate to false, the other css class notOnSale would be added to the element, in your case the checkbox.

There is a lot of documentation and codepen examples that you can take from! Have a nice day! A link, just for the sake of knowledge: https://appendto.com/2016/03/ng-class-use-cases-action/

A practical example taken from treehouse:

```
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="list">
    <div class="item" ng-class="{'editing-item': editing, 'edited': todo.edited}" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <input ng-model="todo.completed" type="checkbox"/>
      <label ng-hide="editing" ng-click="helloWorld()">
        {{todo.name}}</label>
      <input ng-change="todo.edited = true" ng-blur="editing = false;" ng-show="editing" ng-model="todo.name" class="editing-label" type="text"/>
      <div class="actions">
        <a href="" ng-click=" editing = !editing">Edit</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="saveTodo(todo)">Save</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo, $index)"  class="Delete">delete</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    {{todos}}
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried like this. but it toggles all the check box

Comment: can you please give the any sample

Answer (score 0):

In your html:

```
<div id="1" class="mSelected" ng-click="myFunc($event)">{{showproduct.productName}}
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(event) {
    $(event.target).toggleClass("your_css_class");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this clutter the js file with a whole lot of specific id coding?

Comment: Yep, i think you're right! May be, something like $(this).toggleClass() is better?